# Analytical continuation of 2,3,4-point integrals

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, perturbation-theory, analyticity

I was reading a paper that gives a nice collection of all scalar integrals that crop up in QCD loop calculations. Such integrals are computed in some kinematic region and then the authors say the results may be analytically continued if so desired. I just wonder how is this analytic continuation done in practice? It's a relatively short paper and the url is https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1851

The authors state that a particular kinematic region allows for the $i\epsilon$ to be dropped and then one can analytically continue results via the prescription $p_i^2 \rightarrow p_i^2 + i\varepsilon, s_{ij} \rightarrow s_{ij} + i\varepsilon, m_i \rightarrow m_i - i\varepsilon$. I just wonder why this is the case and if the sign choices here are significant?

As a simple example, the analytic continuation of the massive tadpole is given as $I_1^D(m^2) = -\mu^{2\epsilon} \Gamma(\epsilon-1) (m^2-i\varepsilon)^{1-\epsilon}$ but what should I do with this result as it contains an explicit $\varepsilon$ in $m^2-i\varepsilon$?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files, e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1851

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is significant: they are originate from the $+i\varepsilon$ prescription in the Feynman propagators of the original integral.  The sign choices are important to obtain the correct sign for the imaginary part of the loop functions.

Note that these prescriptions are relevant only if evaluations are being made on a branch cut.  Therefore, for your example, if $m^2 > 0$ (which is usually the case), the $-i\varepsilon$ can be dropped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In fact, I have already been using PackageX extensively. In, for example, `LoopIntegrate[1,k,{k,0},{k+p1,mc},{k+p1+p2,mc}]` together with scalar product relations, the package will sometimes just return an expression without me specifying the domain of parameters. In this case, would the expression be valid in the parameter region in which there are no imaginary parts? And how would one in general, through PackageX, specify the parameter region one wants the expression in? Thanks!

Comment: @CAF Ah I missed your comment, sorry.  The expression returned by *Package*-X is supposed to be valid for all real values of the scalar products and all positive values for the internal masses.  Sometimes, results are expressed in terms of `Ln` and `DiLog` to accommodate the $+i\varepsilon$ prescription over the whole domain of reals.  But, if you know that some quantities are restricted to a smaller domain, you can wrap `Assuming` around `LoopRefine` (or `C0Expand`, `D0Expand`, etc), and that will make it try to come up with something in terms of *Mathematica*'s `Log` and `PolyLog` only...

Comment: ...for example you can do something like `Assuming[s<4m^2, ExpandC0[...]]` and then it will try to come up with an explicit form of `ScalarC0` with fewer `Ln` and `DiLog`.  This part of *Package*-X definitely needs more work; in a future version, I'll provide the option `Assumptions` for `LoopRefine`, `C0Expand`, *etc.*, and improve the code to produce better results in cases when some variables are restricted to a smaller domain.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As an example, I tried the following `Assuming[{xb > 1, x < -4*mc^2, mc > 0}, 
 C0Expand[ScalarC0[mc^2, x/4 + mc^2/xb + x/(4 xb), 
   2 mc^2 + x/2 + (2 mc^2)/xb + x/(2 xb), mc, 0, mc]]]`. There is no simplification made from `DiLog` to `PolyLog` that I can see. Does the `Assuming` only work for relatively simpler `ScalarC0` functions?

Comment: In any case, it doesn't take long to analyse term by term to check whether the `DiLog` is a `PolyLog` or a `Conjugate[PolyLog[]]`. The `PolyLog[2,x]` is simply $\text{Li}_2(x)$. Is there a rewriting of `Conjugate[PolyLog[2,x]]`?

Comment: And as a final question if its ok, why does `LoopRefine` sometimes give me an epsilon expansion immediately but other times give me a `ScalarC0` which then becomes an epsilon expansion only after it is within a `C0Expand`?

Comment: @CAF Ah, that example very clearly demonstrates that I need to revisit and improve the code to produce better results!  By playing around I found that you can get a nice result if you throw in `KallenExpand`, `Simplify`, etc as follows:  ``Assuming[{xb > 1, x < -4*mc^2, mc > 0}, 
 C0Expand[ScalarC0[mc^2, x/4 + mc^2/xb + x/(4 xb), 
      2 mc^2 + x/2 + (2 mc^2)/xb + x/(2 xb), mc, 0, mc]] // 
    KallenExpand // Simplify // X`Utilities`SimplifyDiLog]``.  But you *shouldn't* have to do that!  It should produce a nice answer *on its own*.  (btw, `Conjugate[PolyLog[]]` can't be simplified).

Comment: Using `FullSimplify` instead of `Simplify` combines the `Conjugate[PolyLog[...]]` with `PolyLog[...]` to get something in terms of `Pi`.  To answer your last question `LoopRefine` is the only function in *Package*-X that does the $\epsilon$-expansion.  To keep things compact, it abbreviates some $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^0)$ functions in terms of `DiscB`, `ScalarC0`, *etc.*.  So those abbreviations have *no* $\epsilon$ in them.  Expanding functions like `DiscExpand`, `C0Expand` *etc.* only insert the analytic forms for the abbreviations; it does not do any further epsilon expansion.

Comment: By the way, I would really appreciate it if you could send me more of those examples of $C_0$ functions that you expect to simplify under external `Assumptions`.   Would you kindly send me an email containing some more examples?  Getting my hands on examples like those would definitely guide me to improve that part of the code!

Comment: Thanks! Sure, I think I have been in touch with you earlier on last year to request the PVReduce package so I will send a follow up email with some of the integrals I’ve been working with. I’m on holiday just now, however, so I’ll send it when I’m back if that’s ok (no access to mathematica)  Thanks again!